# Only showing one character while printing in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

This is my code:

```
auto text = new wchar_t[WCHAR_MAX];
GetWindowTextW(hEdit, text, WCHAR_MAX);
SetWindowTextW(hWnd, text);
printf_s((const char *)text);
```

While printing, the char (text), it only outputs one character to the console.
It is a WINAPI gui and a console running together. It sets the winapi title successfully and get the text successfully, but i have no idea why this is only printing out one character to the console...

Comment: Please upgrade to a [mcve].

Comment: `(const char *)text` - `text` is `wchar_t*` not `char*`. your cast is wrong. you need  print exactly `wchar_t*`

Comment: Using a text input from a user as the format string to `printf` (any version) is a really big security hole with an exploit waiting to happen. If you need to print a string either use `printf("%s", the_string)` or use `puts`.

Comment: wchar_t * is not to be used as printf takes an argument as const char and just printing it as wchar_t* is unsupported.

Comment: @NashiSM - use `WriteConsoleW` for print `wchar_t*`. or `wprintf_s`, `wprintf` etc. but not `printf_s`

Comment: Your cast tells a big lie to the compiler. Remove the cast and fix the problem that the compiler reported.

Answer (score 3):

You're performing a raw cast from a wide string to a narrow string. This conversion is never safe.

Wide strings are stored as two-byte words in Windows. In your case, the high byte of the first character is `0`, and x86 is little-endian, so the print stops at the first character.